# How to return .xlsx file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

how to return .xlsx file?
For example - when I'm going to "/download" - "File.xlsx" should start downloading.
I'm using bottle 0.12.7 and python 3.4
I try to return it:

```
@route('/download')
def download():
    return open('files/File.xlsx')
```

But Chrome returns me this error: **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

Thanks.

Comment: And what actually happens (with your code that I can't see)?

Comment: @doctorlove question was edited.

Comment: try actually reading the file contents: `return open('files/File.xlsx').read()`

Comment: @ch3ka it returns me "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 788: character maps to <undefined>" when I try to set "encoding='utf-8'" I've "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 15: invalid start byte"

Comment: Does it work any better when you specify binary mode? `open('files/File.xlsx', 'rb').read()`

Comment: @tepples it returns undefined symbols "PK��yE���xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml��MO�0����ܻv��UB�*!J۳7�"

Comment: What `Content-type:` header are you sending?

Comment: @tepples there isn't any special headers

Comment: The docs mention stating content type: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/bottle-docs.pdf (page 9) e.g. `response.content_type = ’text/html; charset=latin9’` it then shows how to download a `static_file`. Is this static?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set the content-type header.

The content-type for Excel files is `application/vnd.ms-excel` for `.xls` files or `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for `.xlsx` files, so try this:

```
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```

Full code:

```
@route('/download')
def download():
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    return open('files/File.xlsx')
```

Comment: Chrome returns me: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Please try with `wget` or `curl` (or even Firefox) and see what response you get.